# How to solve differential equation problem involving Dirac delta function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions, dirac-delta

$$
y''+2y'+ 10y=b\,δ\left(\, t - T\,\right)\,\qquad y\left(\, 0\,\right)=3\,,\quad y'\left(\, 0\,\right)=0
$$

Can you choose values for $b$ and $T$ ( $b$ and $T$ positive numbers) such that $y\left(\, t\,\right) = 0\,,\  \forall\ t > T$ ?.

I am working on this problem. I managed to solve the IVP. The answer is
$$
y\left(\, t\,\right)
=3{\rm e}^{-t}\cos\left(\, 3t\,\right) - {\rm e}^{-t}\sin\left(\, 3t\,\right)
+ 1/3b{\rm e}^{-\left(\, t - T\,\right)}\sin\left(\, 3t - 3T\,\right)
u\left(\, t - T\,\right)
$$. But I am stuck at figuring the values for b and T. Answer given to question above is bn=3Sqrt(10)e^(-Tn) and Tn=1/3 arcsin(3/ sqrt(10)) + 2/3n pi, n=0,1,2...

But I have no idea how to figure out that solution. I would be really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\,{\rm y}''\pars{t} + 2\,{\rm y}'\pars{t} + 10\,{\rm y}\pars{t}
     =b\,δ\pars{t - T}\,,\qquad \,{\rm y}\pars{0}=3\,,\quad \,{\rm y}'\pars{0}=0
     \:\ {\large ?}}$

> The solution is given by:
>   \begin{align}
> \,{\rm y}\pars{t}=
> \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
> \expo{-t}\bracks{3\cos\pars{3t} + \sin\pars{3t}} & \mbox{if} & t < T
> \\[2mm]
> \expo{-t}\bracks{A\cos\pars{3t} + B\sin\pars{3t}} & \mbox{if} & t > T
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

Now, you have two equations to satisfy:
$$
\,{\rm y}\pars{T^{-}} = \,{\rm y}\pars{T^{+}}\,,
\qquad
\,{\rm y}'\pars{T^{+}}  - \,{\rm y}'\pars{T^{-}} = b
$$

> Then, you have two equations which determine $\ds{A\ \mbox{and}\ B}$.

Comment: I am not sure how I could apply this. Could you maybe explain it further?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with $u(t)$ on the answer? Is the function $u$ defined anywhere?
Anyway, I haven't tried the math myself, but if you have the analitic solution, shouldn't the rest come by the initial conditions? Set $y(t)=0$, since you know that $e^0=1$, $sin(0)=0$, $cos(0)=1$ you will have a equation on $b$ and $T$. Do the same for the derivative, you will have a system of two equations and two variables. Then solve it for $b$ and $T$...